# iPad messenger for Windows Live Network

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation, chat

I'm looking for a FREE chat client that supports Windows Live network (Messenger) and is designed for iPad.

The iPad [Windows Live Messenger application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windows-live-messenger/id376196406?mt=8) is designed for iPhone, so when you install it on iPad, you get a iPhone screen application.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo! Messenger](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yahoo!-messenger-free-sms/id309219097?mt=8) says it supports Windows Live/MSN Messenger accounts, and is a Universal (iPhone & iPad) app.

Not free, but only $0.99 is [Live Messenger Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/live-messenger-pro/id394026416?mt=8).

Comment: Tried Yahoo but did not accepted messenger login.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the iPhone app from 1x magnification to 2x. I do it for a bunch of apps that don't have native iPad apps. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for answering a question. However, the OP *specifically* noted that he was looking for an iPad app. He mentioned that he didn't want to use the iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

IMO is free and has been working great for me.

Has great features and supports several protocols.

[Imo](https://imo.im/mobile_ipad)